# Visual Studio Code: How to open a new Python file in a new tab instead of a new window

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

Every time I click a Python file to open it with Visual Studio Code (right click, open with vscode), it opens in a new vscode window.
Instead, I would like to open all the files in a single window, in separate tabs.

Just like the Spyder editor; it opens all the files in separate tabs. When I click yet another file, it will open in the same window in a new tab.

I did some research, people usually talk about the preview issue. I could not find an answer to this question.

PS. I have just installed vscode on my Linux Mint machine. I am new to vscode.

Comment: Go to settings and search for `window.openFilesInNewWindow`. If you set it to off then it will open the files in the existing window.

Comment: Thanks. Strange. It is already `off`! It says in a note "Note that there can still be cases where this setting is ignored (e.g. when using the `--new-window` or `--reuse-window` command line option)." This is probably why (since I right click and choose 'open with vscode', it probably invokes `--new-window`). My default Python editor is Spyder.